# "Exec Format Error" while trying to run a program

Tags: executable, executable-format

First of all, sorry for my english !

OS: XUbuntu VM.

I am trying to compile an executable with a Makefile using clang-9.

I initially faced a permission denied error. Fixed it with chmod.

Now, when i run the following command :

```
./battlespace map btsp
```

(which is the executable in question)

I get the following error:

```
"exec format error".
```

I am unable to find the cause.

Thanks.

Comment: You are apparently trying to run something that isn't actually a program - one of the intermediate files generated during the compilation process, perhaps.  You haven't given enough details to be more specific.

Comment: Please check my edits, and kindly add the required details. This question lacks details.